# ERROR_IO_PENDING on FTP Asynchronous Operation [Wininet C++]

Tags: c++, winapi, asynchronous, ftp, wininet

I've recently been working on an application that needs to establish an FTP connection with a server and download/upload files from it. For performance reasons, I would like to download multiple files at a time. For that reason I've tried to implement asynchronous operation on the `Wininet` API using the `InternetOpen` function along with the `INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC` flag, as well as the `InternetSetStatusCallback` function. Here is a sample of my code, where I want to list all the files in the main directory of the remote server recursively:

```
      /*Global variables*/
            HANDLE MayContinue=0;
            DWORD LatestResult=1;
        /*Prototypes*/
        void CALLBACK CallbackFunction(HINTERNET,DWORD_PTR,DWORD,LPVOID,DWORD);

    //Iteration function called by main()

        void FTPIterate()
            {
                WIN32_FIND_DATAA data;
                HINTERNET Internet;
                INTERNET_STATUS_CALLBACK call;
                HINTERNET h_file;

                 MayContinue = ::CreateEvent (NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);
                iconnect=InternetOpen(NULL,INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY,proxy_url,NULL,INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC);
                call=InternetSetStatusCallback(iconnect,(INTERNET_STATUS_CALLBACK)CallbackFunction);

                while(f[FLAG_FTP_ITERATE])
                {
                    MayContinue = ::CreateEvent(NULL,FALSE,FALSE,NULL);
                    InternetConnect(iconnect,ftp_url,INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT,ftp_user,ftp_pass,INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP,NULL,LatestResult);
                       WaitForSingleObject (MayContinue, INFINITE);
                       server=(HINTERNET)LatestResult;
                           printf("Server handle: %i\n",(int)server);
                           printf("Server Error: %i\n",GetLastError());
                           SetLastError(0);
                        MayContinue = ::CreateEvent(NULL,FALSE,FALSE,NULL);
                        FtpFindFirstFile(server,ftp_base,&data,INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE,LatestResult);
                        WaitForSingleObject(MayContinue,INFINITE);
                        h_file=(HINTERNET)LatestResult;
                            //do stuff
                            printf("FindFirstFile handle: %i\n",(int)h_File);
                        while((MayContinue = ::CreateEvent(NULL,FALSE,FALSE,NULL)) && InternetFindNextFileA(h_file,&data))
                        {
                            WaitForSingleObject(MayContinue,INFINITE);
                            //do stuff
                        }
                              printf("FindNextFile Error: %i\n",GetLastError()); //loop is never executed
                    InternetCloseHandle(server);
                }   

            }

        void CALLBACK CallbackFunction(HINTERNET hInternet,DWORD_PTR dwContext,DWORD dwInternetStatus,LPVOID lpvStatusInformation,DWORD dwStatusInformationLength)
        {
        if (dwInternetStatus == INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_COMPLETE)
          {
            LatestResult = ((LPINTERNET_ASYNC_RESULT)lpvStatusInformation)->dwResult;
            SetEvent (MayContinue);
          }
        }
```

My code is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358536/access-violation-using-ftpfindfirstfile-unicode-version-in-async-mode/22148463#22148463) post from Stack Overflow. When I run it, I first of all get an error after the call to `InternetConnect`, which is `ERROR_IO_PENDING`. According to the WinAPI reference this means that there's still some operation being performed. Shouldn't the call to `WaitForSingleObject` prevent this from happening? (actually, the `HINTERNET` handle returned by `InternetConnect` seems to be valid).
When I call the `FtpFindFirstFile` function it correctly retrieves the first file, but when I use the HINTERNET handle (which, again, seems to be valid) returned by it in the `InternetFindNextFile` function it fails with error `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`.

**EDIT:** I egt those errors when using Remy's code:

```
Connect Handle 00CC0004
Waiting for server handle
    Unable to find first file. OS Error: 6 //aren't those calls to FindFirstFile weird if InternetConnect hasn't returned yet?
Waiting for server handle
    Unable to find first file. OS Error: 6
Waiting for server handle
    Unable to find first file. OS Error: 6
Waiting for server handle
    Unable to find first file. OS Error: 6
Waiting for server handle
    Unable to find first file. OS Error: 6
Waiting for server handle
    Unable to find first file. OS Error: 6
Waiting for server handle.
Unable to connect to Server. Inet Error: 12015 Waiting for server handle
```

Can someone help me find the mistake?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: "I first of all get an error after the call to `InternetConnect`, which is `ERROR_IO_PENDING`" - you know this *how* ? You don't seem to be checking the result of `InternetConnect` for a successful HANDLE return value, nor is there any code that checks then subpaths to `GetLastError()` in the event of a NULL return handle.

Comment: @WhozCraig As I say in the post, error I've omitted error checking for clarity. Indeed, in my source code, I check the HANDLE returned by `InternetConnect` (after the call to `WaitForSingleObject`), casting it to an ìnt` (which isn't null) and then call `GetLastError()`, which returns `997`. Similar checking is performed later after `FtpFindFirstFile` and `InternetFindNextFile`. I'm editting the snippet to show it.

Comment: ERROR_IO_PENDING is not actually an error.  It simply means that the I/O operation has been successfully started, but is not yet complete.  Since you requested asynchronous operation, ERROR_IO_PENDING is normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ERROR_IO_PENDING` error is coming from `InternetOpen()` itself.  Since `WaitForSingleObject()` is succeeding, it is not overwriting `GetLastError()` (it only does so on error, as most APIs do), so the error is being carried over from the result of `InternetOpen()`.  This is **not** the correct way to use `GetLastError()`.  Assume that all APIs overwrite `GetLastError()` (if documented to use `GetLastError()` at all), and make sure you call it *immediately* only if an API fails (unless documented as being used during success conditions).

What your code is doing is **NOT** asynchronous!  You are issuing asynchronous API calls, but you are waiting for their results, which defeats the purpose.  Your code is acting synchronously, the same as if you were to omit the `INTERNAL_FLAG_ASYNC` flag and `WaitForSingleObject()` calls (not to mention you are leaking event resource by calling `CreateEvent()` unnecessarily), eg:

```
void LogError(const char *Op)
{
    DWORD err = GetLastError();

    if (err == ERROR_INTERNET_EXTENDED_ERROR)
    {
        LPSTR szBuffer;
        DWORD dwLength = 0;

        InternetGetLastResponseInfoA(&err, NULL, &dwLength);
        if (GetLastError() != INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            printf("%s. Unknown Inet Error. OS Error: %u", Op, GetLastError());
            return;
        }

        szBuffer = new char[dwLength+1];
        InternetGetLastResponseInfoA(&err, szBuffer, &dwLength);
        szBuffer[dwLength] = 0;

        printf("%s. Inet Error: %u %s", Op, err, szBuffer);
        delete[] szBuffer;
    }
    else
    {
        LPSTR lpBuffer = NULL;
        DWORD dwLen = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, err, 0, (LPSTR)&lpBuffer, 0, NULL);

        if (lpBuffer)
        {
            printf("%s. OS Error: %u %s", Op, err, lpBuffer);
            LocalFree(lpBuffer);
        }
        else
            printf("%s. OS Error: %u", Op, err);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

void FTPIterate()
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA data;
    HINTERNET hConnect;
    HINTERNET hServer;
    HINTERNET hFile;

    hConnect = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY, proxy_url, NULL, 0);
    if (hConnect == NULL)
    {
        LogError("Unable to Open Internet");
        return;
    }

    printf("Connect handle: %p\n", hConnect);

    while (f[FLAG_FTP_ITERATE])
    {
        printf("Connecting to Server\n");

        hServer = InternetConnect(hConnect, ftp_url, INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, ftp_user, ftp_pass, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, NULL, 0);
        if (hServer == NULL)
        {
            LogError("Unable to connect to Server");
            continue;
        }

    printf("Connected to Server. Server handle: %p\n", hServer);
        printf("Finding first file\n");

        hFile = FtpFindFirstFileA(hServer, ftp_base, &data, INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE, 0);
        if (hFile == NULL)
        {
            if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
                printf("No files were found\n");
            else
                LogError("Unable to find first file");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Find handle: %p\n", hFile);

            do
            {
                //do stuff

                printf("Finding next file\n");

                if (!InternetFindNextFileA(hFile, &data))
                {
                    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
                        printf("No more files were found\n");
                    else
                        LogError("Unable to find next file")

                    break;
                }
            }
            while (true);

            InternetCloseHandle(hFile);
        }

        InternetCloseHandle(hServer);
    }   

    InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
}
```

To make this code run asynchronously, get rid of all off the waits and implement a state machine that your callback advances as needed, eg:

```
enum FTPState {ftpConnect, ftpWaitingForConnect, ftpFindFirstFile, ftpWaitingForFirstFind, ftpFindNextFile, ftpWaitingForNextFind, ftpProcessFile, ftpDisconnect};

struct REQ_CONTEXT
{
    FTPState State;
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA data;
    HINTERNET hConnect;
    HINTERNET hServer;
    HINTERNET hFile;
    HANDLE hDoneEvent;
};

void LogError(const char *Op, DWORD err)
{
    if (err == ERROR_INTERNET_EXTENDED_ERROR)
    {
        LPSTR szBuffer;
        DWORD dwLength = 0;

        InternetGetLastResponseInfoA(&err, NULL, &dwLength);
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
        {
            printf("%s. Unknown Inet Error. OS Error: %u", Op, GetLastError());
            return;
        }

        szBuffer = new char[dwLength+1];
        InternetGetLastResponseInfoA(&err, szBuffer, &dwLength);
        szBuffer[dwLength] = 0;

        printf("%s. Inet Error: %u %s", Op, err, szBuffer);
        delete[] szBuffer;
    }
    else
    {
        LPSTR lpBuffer = NULL;
        DWORD dwLen = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, NULL, err, 0, (LPSTR)&lpBuffer, 0, NULL);

        if (lpBuffer)
        {
            printf("%s. OS Error: %u %s", Op, err, lpBuffer);
            LocalFree(lpBuffer);
        }
        else
            printf("%s. OS Error: %u", Op, err);
    }

    printf("\n");
}

void LogError(const char *Op)
{
    LogError(Op, GetLastError());
}

void DoNextStep(REQ_CONTEXT *ctx)
{
    do
    {
        if ((ctx->State == ftpConnect) && (!f[FLAG_FTP_ITERATE]))
        {
            printf("Done!\n");
            SetEvent(ctx->hDoneEvent);
            return;
        }

        switch (ctx->State)
        {
            case ftpConnect:
            {
                printf("Connecting to Server\n");

                HINTERNET hServer = InternetConnect(ctx->hConnect, ftp_url, INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, ftp_user, ftp_pass, INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, NULL, (DWORD_PTR)ctx);
                if (hServer != NULL)
                {
                    if (ctx->hServer == NULL)
                    {
                        ctx->hServer = hServer;
                        printf("Server handle: %p\n", ctx->hServer);
                    }

                    printf("Connected to Server\n");
                    ctx->State = ftpFindFirstFile;
                }
                else if (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
                {
                    if (ctx->hServer == NULL)
                        printf("Waiting for Server handle\n");

                    printf("Waiting for Server connect to complete\n");
                    ctx->State = ftpWaitingForConnect;
                }
                else
                    LogError("Unable to connect to Server");

                break;
            }

            case ftpWaitingForConnect:
                return;

            case ftpFindFirstFile:
            {
                printf("Finding first file\n");

                HINTERNET hFile = FtpFindFirstFileA(ctx->hServer, ftp_base, &ctx->data, INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE, (DWORD_PTR)ctx);
                if (hFile != NULL)
                {
                    if (ctx->hFile == NULL)
                    {
                        ctx->hFile = hFile;
                        printf("Find handle: %p\n", ctx->hFile);
                    }

                    ctx->State = ftpProcessFile;
                }
                else if (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
                {
                    if (ctx->hFile == NULL)
                        printf("Waiting for Find handle\n");

                    printf("Waiting for Find to complete\n");
                    ctx->State = ftpWaitingForFirstFind;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
                        printf("No files were found\n");
                    else
                        LogError("Unable to find first file");

                    ctx->State = ftpDisconnect;
                }

                break;
            }

            case ftpWaitingForFirstFind:
            case ftpWaitingForNextFind:
                return;

            case ftpProcessFile:
            {
                //do stuff

                printf("Finding next file\n");
                if (!InternetFindNextFileA(ctx->hFile, &ctx->data))
                {
                    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING)
                    {
                        printf("Waiting for next file to complete\n");

                        ctx->State = ftpWaitingForNextFind;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
                            printf("No more files were found\n");
                        else
                            LogError("Unable to find next file");

                        ctx->State = ftpDisconnect;
                    }
                }

                break;
            }

            case ftpDisconnect:
            {
                printf("Disconnecting\n");

                if (ctx->hFile != NULL)
                {
                    InternetCloseHandle(ctx->hFile);
                    ctx->hFile = NULL;
                }

                if (ctx->hServer != NULL)
                {
                    InternetCloseHandle(ctx->hServer);
                    ctx->hServer = NULL;
                }

                ctx->State = ftpConnect;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while (true);
}

void CALLBACK CallbackFunction(HINTERNET hInternet, DWORD_PTR dwContext, DWORD dwInternetStatus, LPVOID lpvStatusInformation, DWORD dwStatusInformationLength)
{
    REQ_CONTEXT *ctx = (REQ_CONTEXT*) dwContext;

    switch (dwInternetStatus)
    {
        case INTERNET_STATUS_HANDLE_CREATED:
        {
            LPINTERNET_ASYNC_RESULT Result = (LPINTERNET_ASYNC_RESULT) lpvStatusInformation;

            switch (ctx->State)
            {
                case ftpConnect:
                case ftpWaitingForConnect:
                    ctx->hServer = (HINTERNET) Result->dwResult;
                    printf("Server handle: %p\n", ctx->hServer);
                    break;

                case ftpFindFirstFile:
                case ftpWaitingForFirstFind:
                    ctx->hFile = (HINTERNET) Result->dwResult;
                    printf("Find handle: %p\n", ctx->hFile);
                    break;
            }

            break;
        }

        case INTERNET_STATUS_REQUEST_COMPLETE:
        {
            LPINTERNET_ASYNC_RESULT Result = (LPINTERNET_ASYNC_RESULT) lpvStatusInformation;

            switch (ctx->State)
            {
                case ftpWaitingForConnect:
                {
                    if (!Result->dwResult)
                    {
                        LogError("Unable to connect to Server", Result->dwError);
                        ctx->State = ftpDisconnect;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        printf("Connected to Server\n");
                        ctx->State = ftpFindFirstFile;
                    }

                    break;
                }

                case ftpWaitingForFirstFind:
                case ftpWaitingForNextFind:
                {
                    if (!Result->dwResult)
                    {
                        if (Result->dwError == ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES)
                            printf("No %sfiles were found\n", (ctx->State == ftpWaitingForNextFind) ? "more " : "");
                        else if (ctx->State == ftpWaitingForFirstFind)
                            LogError("Unable to find first file", Result->dwError);
                        else
                            LogError("Unable to find next file", Result->dwError);

                        ctx->State = ftpDisconnect;
                    }
                    else
                        ctx->State = ftpProcessFile;

                    break;
                }
            }

            DoNextStep(ctx);
            break;
        }
    }
}

void FTPIterate()
{
    REQ_CONTEXT ctx = {0};
    ctx.State = ftpConnect;

    ctx.hDoneEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (ctx.hDoneEvent == NULL)
    {
        LogError("Unable to Create Done Event");
        return;
    }

    ctx.hConnect = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY, proxy_url, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC);
    if (ctx.hConnect == NULL)
    {
        LogError("Unable to Open Internet");
        CloseHandle(ctx.hDoneEvent);
        return;
    }

    printf("Connect handle: %p\n", ctx.hConnect);
    InternetSetStatusCallback(ctx.hConnect, &CallbackFunction);

    DoNextStep(&ctx);
    WaitForSingleObject(ctx.hDoneEvent, INFINITE);

    InternetCloseHandle(ctx.hConnect);
    CloseHandle(ctx.hDoneEvent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As for the Error Codes, isn't the SetLastError reseting the codes to SUCCES? About asynchronous operations, my goal isn't to perform them on indexing but later on downloading, although that part of the code wasn't shown. Thanks for your help!

Comment: On the first iteration of the loop, you are not calling `SetLastError()` until after you have logged the error that was carried over from `InternetConnect()`.

Comment: O sorry. I thought you were talking about `InternetConnect()`instead of `InternetOpen`. Indeed I didn't handle the error from that function properly. Thanks again.

Comment: When I compile your code the `InternetConnect` function returns a `NULL`handle. The error code is `ERROR_IO_PENDING` for a certain number of calls to `DoNextRequest()` (it enters the first case of the `switch()`, sets the error and then returns) until it changes to `ERROR_INTERNET_OUT_OF_HANDLES`. The same function performs well on sync mode. Where does the error come from?

Comment: My mistake, I wasn't handling the `ERROR_IO_PENDING` state correctly.  I have updated the code.

Comment: It's now failing with `ERROR_INTERNET_LOGIN_FAILURE`. I guess this has nothing to do wih async operations, does it? Additionally, how might I now implement the capability of downloading all the files that it has found?

Comment: You are asking questions that are not relevant to this discussion.  This discussion is about how to write async logic and handling `ERROR_IO_PENDING`.  That has been answered.  Anything else outside of that should be posted as new questions (how to handle authentication, how to download files, etc) if you can't figure it out. Authentication is handled by `InternetConnect()` ([see this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384220.aspx)), downloading is handled by [`FtpGetFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384157.aspx).

Comment: Remy, I haven't asked you for advice on how to handle authentication. I only wanted you to tell me if the 12015 error can be caused by something related with async calls or if it is, without doubt, unrelated to it. Secondly, I know how to download files using `FTPGetFile()`, what I'm asking you to tell me is how to download files in async mode without having troubles again with callback functions. I think this is pretty relevant to this discussion, because it's been the subject since the beginning.

Comment: How to handle authentication and how to download files asynchronously are separate questions not related to this discussion's question.  This discussion's question has been answered as asked. StackOverflow guidelines are clear on this matter. Different questions should be kept separate. In any case, a login failure has nothing to do with asynchronous, you are likely just providing bad credentials. And `FtpGetFile()` works asynchronously the same way the other functions do - call it, and if you get an I/O pending error then wait for the callback to tell you when the download is finished.

Comment: Actually, when I try to connect with the same credentials, but without using your code or any form of asynchronous call I don't get any error and can perform FTP operations. From the moment I try to connect in async mode using your code, I get `ERROR_INTERNET_LOGIN_FAILURE`. I'm going to edit the question to show the info I get on the console line.

Comment: I updated my answer with some additional code.  This code works fine for me connecting to my FTP server.

Comment: It now seems to be working perfectly. Let me thank you again.